# Разница между size и length

Tags: c++, строки

В чём разница между `std::string::size` и `std::string::length`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ни в чём. Разницы нет. Это просто два метода, с разным именем, которые возвращают одно и тоже. Просто `length` как бы более «строковое» имя, хотя его и мало кто использует, по моему опыту.